# Get score value from serializable class to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, serialization

I am developing a game in which I've a serializable class that has a score parameter and it is set to 0 initially.
Now what I want that when the score is greater than 1 then the score value is passed to my main activity and some toast is shown in the main activity
This is my code for **serializable** class:

```
public class Game implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8326065952389292265L;
private int score = 0;
```

Here is my score increase and when it is greater than 1 then the score value should be passed to main activity

```
if(bird.GetX()+bW > px1 && bird.GetX() < px2)
            {
                if(birdY1>=minY && birdY2<=maxY)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!boom)
                        SoundManager.playSound(5, 1);

                    boom = true;
                    bird.SetState(0);
                }
                score = (i+1);
                if (score>1)
                {

                }

            }
```

I am confused how to send this score value to my main activity and then how to get it in main activity. Can anyone help me some little code that how it is done? Any help will be appreciated

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private SurfaceView mainGameView;
static Bitmap bitmap;
static Canvas canvas;
private GameLogic gameLogic;
private Game gamescore;
private ArrayList<String> wordsDictionary;
private Context context;
private MyTask mt;
private boolean dictionaryLoaded;
private ImageView image;
private Activity activity;

Intent playbackServiceIntent; 

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this;

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    SoundManager.getInstance();
    SoundManager.initSounds(this);
    SoundManager.loadSounds();

    SoundManager.playSound(1, 1);

    if(true)
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    else
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);


    context = this;
    gameLogic = new GameLogic(context, getResources());



    dictionaryLoaded = false;

    SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data1 = sPref.getString("data1", "");
    mainGameView = new MainGameView(this, gameLogic);

    final RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    layout.addView(mainGameView);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();

    if(true)
    {
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: make method in Game class that return score

Comment: @pcpriyanka I tried with that last day as some one suggested but nothing showed up when score reaches 1

Comment: How Game related to the MainActivity, is it field of MainActivity.class or they just "chatting" through messages. In short, could you please provide code of MainActivity?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin I just edited it Please check :)

Comment: @ArslanAli Okey. Next question is how you interact with Game. Do you use direct method calls, or Game is runned in another thread or service?

Comment: when your score is reaches 1, have you updated value of score in game calss

Comment: it is running in another thread sir

Comment: @pcpriyanka yes (i+1) is basically score increase and then i put condition

Comment: (i+1) is in your mainActivity rigth ?

Comment: @pcpriyanka no it is in the serializable class
please check my code above

Comment: in that class have you written getter and setter method to get and set the score

Comment: @pcpriyanka No i haven't, can you please provide some example code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123948/discussion-between-pcpriyanka-and-arslan-ali).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void setScore(int s) {
score=s;
}

public static int getScore()
{
return score;
}
```

Now you can use as in your main Activity :

```
int scr=Game.getScore();
```

above code will return the score

Answer (score 0):

Create one interface

```
 public interface GameScoreListener{
  void onScoreIncrease(int incrementBy);
  void onScoreDecrease(int decrementBy)
}
```

Implement `GameScoreListener` in `MainActivity`.
Create `GameScoreListener` setter and getter in the class where you're changing score. When Score change in any method check `GameScoreListener` for NPE, then make callback from `GameScoreListener`.